# How to write a Webapp2 Request Handler to Allow Client to Get Data after receiving Channel API message

Tags: python, webapp2, channel-api, requesthandler

As a follow up to [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654543/what-python-web-framework-should-i-use-with-gwt-to-stream-kml-from-python-back-e), I have a basic question about the easiest way to get a webapp2 python server to provide json data that is too large (about 100 kb) to send as a Channel API message to a client .

The webapp2 server generates several data files over several minutes based on a client request, and I am thinking that I would like the Channel API to send messages with the url to the client when the data is ready, and the client (a GWT app) could perform a http GET request to get the data.  Each data file is unique to the client and therefore the server will have to have a request handler that will give the appropriate data file for the client.

Can you write a request handler that can provide the correct data file directly from another request handler for that particular client when the request is called?  Or Do I need to store the data using Cloud SQL or the Data Store first until the client asks for it?  Here is some incomplete sample code of what I would like to do:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    ## This opens the GWT app    

class Service_handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self, parameters):
    ## This is called by the GWT app and generates the data to be 
    ## sent to the client. 
    ## A channel API message is sent to the client with the url 
    ## for each data file generated.

class kml_handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self, client_id):
    ##  I would like to return the correct data here when it is 
    ##  called by the client.  Do I need to store the data in  
    ##  Cloud SQL or the Data Store and then retrieve it
    ##  or can this handler take the results directly from the 
    ##  Service_handler as soon as it is generated?

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                            webapp2.Route(r'/', handler=MainPage),
                            webapp2.Route(r'/Service/', handler=Service_handler),
                            webapp2.Route(r'/_ah/channel/<connected>/', handler = connection_handler),
                            webapp2.Route(r'/kml/<client_id>', handler = kml_handler)
                            ],
                          debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write files to the blobstore and serve those files from the blobstore.

Here is an example:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview#Complete_Sample_App

Comment: Thanks. Using the blobstore seems like the best solution. However, for now it is simpler for me to write the long text data across several records in the data store and then join them back together when they are queried as a response to the http request (which also works).  I will likely switch to using the blobstore eventually.

Comment: You can also use a datastore db.Text property to save the json string, and in NDB there is a json property to save a json object. NDB takes care of load and dump.